# Django and woocommerce

Tags: python, django, rest, woocommerce

I am trying to use the REST api to link a wordpress e-commerce (using woocommerce) website and a Django app.
My question is, how can I execute a python script inside Django, and return data after a purchase has been made on the e-commerce website.

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce now has a REST webhooks API that can *push* orders to your django when orders are made/updated/deleted - its great.

I'm doing this with my site Adventuretickets.nl - you can ask for code samples.

Google woocommerce webhooks API for documentation on what exactly they will send you on new order. You can write normal django views to receive the JSON.

If you do need to pull from Woocommerce, you can use package django-woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by installing [Celery, RabbitMQ and Supervisor on the Django server](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), and creating a Celery worker (managed by Supervisor) that [polled WooCommerce](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WooCommerce) for new purchases.

I'm currently using [quite naive polling](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WooCommerce). If you are handling vast numbers of purchases, you may need a different strategy.